# How to pronounce 伝統色

Tags: readings

I have a book called 日本の伝統色 and I'm confused if 色 should be pronounced as いろ or しょく.

Someone said to me that the correct way to say it is いろ to avoid confusion with 食, but [Wikipedia](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E4%BC%9D%E7%B5%B1%E8%89%B2)  says it is しょく。

Answer (score 6):

「伝統色」 is read 「でんとうしょく」, period.  It is not natural to read it 「でんとういろ」 because that is a combination of on-reading and kun-reading.

I have no idea who this "someone" is, but I just cannot think of a situation/context where the reading 「でんとうしょく」 could confuse a native speaker regarding its meaning.

(Note, however, that I am not saying all this because that is what Wiki says.  It is just that my Japanese ears won't take the unnatural reading of 「でんとういろ」 at all.)

If you want to read 「色」 as 「いろ」, the phrase needs to be changed to:

・「日本の伝統**の**色」

・「日本伝統**の**色」, etc.